# SQL: Set record to system Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can set a column in a table to accept only the system date or greater than? what would be the sql query?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today's date corresponds to midnight today so if you want to be able to add dates from today also you need something like

```
ColumnName >= select DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
((DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())*3600000)+(DATEPART(mi, GETDATE())*60000)+(DATEPART(s,  GETDATE())*1000) +DATEPART(MILLISECOND,GETDATE()))*-1,
    GETDATE())
```

Comment: so should the query be like this? `ALTER TABLE Products 

       ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK1
       CHECK
       (ParkingStartDate >= select DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
((DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())*3600000)+(DATEPART(mi, GETDATE())*60000)+(DATEPART(s,  GETDATE())*1000) +DATEPART(MILLISECOND,GETDATE()))*-1,
    GETDATE())`

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE table1
       ADD CONSTRAINT chk1
       CHECK
       (date_column >= GETDATE ())
```

Comment: It shows this error: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHECK1". The conflict occurred in database "C:\QSF_LOCAL\DEV\TELERIK.WEB.EXAMPLES\APP_DATA\NORTHWIND.MDF", table "dbo.Products", column 'ParkingStartDate'.

Comment: @Humam Shbib - Perhaps you already have a check constraint (CHECK1) and you need to add this condition to the existing check constraint then?

Comment: @Humam Shibb - Check to see if you have any existing data in the table that would violate this constraint. If so, you have to clean that out first or it won't let you create the constraint.

Comment: Solved It, Had to remove all the data inserted already into the column, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Check Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)**:

```
ColumnName >= getdate()
```